# Serial line editing

Tags: c, serial-port, vt100

I'm working on a micro controller with a serial terminal and I want to be able to backspace characters, I'm already handling it in the input buffer, but I don't know what to send through serial to delete it from the terminal emulator, sending \b only moves the cursor back. ¿Anyone knows how to handle this in VT100?

Comment: You can't backspace on serial port connections, I think. [source](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/backspace.html), well, it probably depends on the software you're using to read the serial port.

Comment: Use "\b \b" instead.

Comment: Nice, thanks @HansPassant , that worked, and is better than what I came up with after posting which was "\b\e[K", that deletes from the cursor to the end of the line (which worked because I haven't implemented moving through the line, and I don't think I will, at least soon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Hans Passant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comment:

> Use "\b \b" instead. –